# How to get select/dropdown value and pass it to url parameter using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

**View**

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'get']) !!}
<div class='col-md-4'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Food</label>
        {!!  Form::select('food', ['1' => 'Western', '0' => 'Eastern'], null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class='col-md-4'>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Beverage</label>
        {!!  Form::select('beverage', ['1' => 'Hot', '0' => 'Cold'], null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pull-left">
    <a type="button" href="WHAT_SHOULD_I_PUT_HERE_?"></a>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get("eat/choose/{food}/{beverage}", "Restaurant@eatAndDrink");
```

As you can see my codes in **views**, I have 2 select/dropdown which is **Food** and **Beverage**. How do I get these value (after user choose) and send them in the url?

For example if user choose Food(Western) and Beverage(Hot), I guess the url will be like this? `<a type="{{url('eat/choose')}}/1/1"></a>` correct me if im wrong.

Comment: you can put action here, {!! Form::open(['method'=>'get', 'url' => 'eat/choose']) !!} and instead of anchor you can take submit button, it makes get request so your parameters are url encoded formate

Comment: the url become `eat/choose?food=1&beverage=1` I wanted the url become `eat/choose/1/1`

Comment: You can use ajax in that case get you parameters in javascript and make url as you want

Comment: if i may ask, any ideas how to do this?

Comment: `var x = document.getElementsByName("food");`
`$.ajax({
            url: "'{{route('eat.choose')}}'+x+'",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                alert(res);
            }
        });`

Comment: not sure i got this error `Route [eat.choose] not defined`

Comment: try like this `url: "'eat/choose/'+x+'",`

Comment: thats get rid of the error, but still have this `eat/choose?food=1&beverage=1`in my url bar...there is no alert message as well...but when i check in my console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` and `eat/'eat/choose/'+x+'`

Comment: Have you checked your network pannel in inspect?
what url ajax is making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, maybe you can redirect to the page using jquery or you can create a form using jquery and submit it dynamically.

For example if you want to redirect you can do like this:

```
$('button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var food = $('[name="food"]').val();
    var beverage = $('[name="beverage"]').val();
    var linkURL = '/eat/choose/'+food+'/'+beverage; //Your route url
    window.location.href=linkURL;
});
```

or if you want like submit form you can do like this:

```
var food = $('[name="food"]').val();
var beverage = $('[name="beverage"]').val();
var linkURL = '/eat/choose/'+food+'/'+beverage; //Your route url
$('<form action="'+linkURL+'"></form>').appendTo('body').submit();
```

This is just an example you can also add validations if you want but I think you will get an idea. Hope that can help you.
Good luck !